# Restoring a checkpoint if ckpt.index file is missing

Tags: tensorflow

Is it possible to restore a checkpoint if `ckpt.index` file is missing, and only `ckpt.data`, `meta` and `.pb` (the frozen model corresponding to this checkpoint) files are available?

Context: I want to load the model from the checkpoint and resume training.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to have `ckpt.index` file as well.